# d3.js - CircleLayout

Tags: d3.js

I am looking for an implementation of a CirlceLayout with d3.js as it is included in the flare toolkit:

http://flare.prefuse.org/api/flare/vis/operator/layout/CircleLayout.html

This layout places items in a circular layout. As far as I see this layout is not yet included in the d3.js library.

If this is not implemented yet I would appreciate some advice how to achieve this with the existing layouts.

thanks

martin

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_layout

UPDATE:

I have by now implemented a prototype of what I want to accomplish

[Circular Layout Prototype](http://justdharma.com/d3/radial-sub-graph/)

following Tyson's suggestion to use the TreeLayout of the d3.js library. The source of this example is a terrible hack which I didn't clean up, so I wouldn't particular recommend to look at it. Basically the program computes a spanning tree of the underlying graph, adds this information to the data so that the TreeLayout can be used to compute the positions of the nodes. The links are taken from the original graph data (not the one of the spanning tree). Procedure as usual ...
Just proof of concept level!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree layout should get you what you are looking for: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout

It might be easy to overlook but the key is the size parameter of the layout:

> Although the layout has a size in x and y, this represents an
>   arbitrary coordinate system; for example, you can treat x as a radius
>   and y as an angle to produce a radial rather than Cartesian layout.

Comment: Thanks Tyson. I was looking into the TreeLayout yet it seems particular shaped for a tree structure. i wont have a parent children relationship in my data and hesitating transforming the data into this structure. Actually I have a graph and might work with a spanning tree alogrithm yet the problem with the TreeLayout for me is that the layout should not position the nodes according to the number of children as it seems to do in the TreeLayout. But I most likely confuse things here as usual